# Number stored as text to number with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have some columns that have cells that are "Number stored as text", which is causing problems with other code that is trying to copy one range to another
`rng1.Copy Destination:=rng2`

The destination range (`rng2`) is blank. Not had this issue with any other data, just when these "Number stored as text" are there, so I need to, via VBA, be able to convert them to number.

Looking around there seems to be two methods for this, but neither are working for me...

TextToColumnns:

```
rng1.Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range(rng1), DataType:=xlDelimited
```

Value = value:

```
Range(rng1).Select
    With Selection
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
```

Other ways I have discovered are 100+ lines of code long which surely cannot be right??

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: what do you mean by, `but neither are working for me`?  do they error or not produce the output desired?

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with something like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    With Selection
        .NumberFormat = "0.00"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert them with this:

```
Function text_to_number(txt As String) As Double
    text_to_number = txt * 1.0
End Function
```

So, first of all, you need to convert them, and after this, copy to another place.
Something like this:

```
Sub copy_and_paste()
    Dim numbers(30) As Double


    'Copping from range A1:A30
    For i = 1 To 30
        numbers(i) = text_to_number(Cells(i, 1).Value)
    Next i

    'Pasting tn B1:B30
    For i = i To 30
        Cells(i, 2).Value = numbers(i)
    Next i


End Sub
```